# Convert Boolean to boolean (java)

Tags: java, decimalformat

Im trying to convert a String to BigDecimal.

I found that I need to set DecimalFormat's setparseBigDecimal to true
then call parse. Unfortunately I keep getting the error that setParseBigDecimal only accepts boolean (not Boolean). I get that so I tried to do this

```
DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue())
```

But I still get the the same error. I even tried these but still didnt work

```
DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(1)
DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true)
boolean x= true;
DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(x)
```

Here's the code.

```
DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue())
DecimalFormat.parse(AmountUtil.formatForSavingOrConversion(taxAmountList.get(i)),0)
```

Comment: Could you be more clear in asking or like showing the code?

Comment: What's the point of using `Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue()` instead of simply `true`?

Comment: Autoboxing should take care of it...BUT, `setParseBigDecimal` isn't a `static` method

Comment: What happens when you just do `DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true)`?

Comment: `setParseBigDecimal` is NOT `static`, you need an instance of `DecimalFormat` to use it, `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();` then `df.setParseBigDecimal(Boolean.valueOf(true));` or `df.setParseBigDecimal(true);` works just fine...

Comment: @MadProgrammer `Boolean.valueOf` returns `Boolean` not `boolean` (not that it really matters OP should be able to even use `Boolean.TRUE` or simply `true`) :)

Comment: @Pshemo That's my point, either will work because autoboxing should take care of it.  The problem isn't the use of `Boolean` or `boolean`, the problem is that `setParseBigDecimal` isn't a `static` method :P

Comment: @user3714598 Please update your question and post error message you are getting.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight even if I put true, it is still giving the same error. that's why I come up with that

Comment: @ PatrickvD still gives me the same error :(

Comment: @user3714598 "still gives me the same error" which is...? You still didn't post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue())
DecimalFormat.parse(AmountUtil.formatForSavingOrConversion(taxAmountList.get(i)),0)
```

won't work because `setParseBigDecimal` and `parse` are NOT `static` methods, you need create an instance of `DecimalFormat` before you can use it...

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
```

Then...

```
df.setParseBigDecimal(Boolean.valueOf(true));
// or
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
```

works fine.  You would then use this instance to parse the values you need

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of `Boolean`, using it as a `boolean` shouldn't cause any errors (the other way doesn't always work). However, if you *really* want an instance of `boolean`, use one of the following two:

```
Boolean object = new Boolean(<<<VALUE>>>);
boolean primitive = object;
```

OR

```
Boolean object = new Boolean(<<<VALUE>>>);
boolean primitive = object.booleanValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to convert a String to BigDecimal

Your question subject and what you are actually trying to do is misleading. To parse a string that contains a decimal number you can easily do-

```
String someValue = "99999999999999999999.99999";
BigDecimal someDecimal = new BigDecimal(someValue);
```

If your string contains comma or the like, strip them out first.